# How to fill a tensor in C++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm creating a tensor like this:

```
tensorflow::Tensor a(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape());
```

I know how to fill a scalar value:

```
a.scalar<float>()() = 8.0;
```

But I don't know how to fill a tensor like [1, 4, 2].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few options. If the tensor is really a small vector, like in your case, you can do the following :

```
tensorflow::Tensor a(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape(3));
a.vec<float>()(0) = 1.0f;
a.vec<float>()(1) = 4.0f;
a.vec<float>()(2) = 2.0f;
```

If you want to construct a slightly larger and/or multi-dimensional tensor, then `tensorflow::ops::Input::Initializer` declared in `tensorflow/cc/framework/ops.h` has many constructors that lets you construct a `Tensor` from various kinds of C++ constants such as simple primitive constants and nested initializer lists representing a multi-dimensional array.

For example, if you want to construct a `2x2` matrix, you can do the following :

```
#include "tensorflow/cc/framework/cc/ops.h"

tensorflow::ops::Input::Initializer a({{1, 2}, {3, 4}});
// a.tensor will be a Tensor with type DT_INT32 and shape {2, 2}.
```

Comment: Hey. I tried first example and tensorflow::TensorShape(3) gives me a syntax error. #include "tensorflow/cc/framework/cc/ops.h" tells me it doesn't exist. Did this change? (I'm new to C++) tensorflow::TensorShape({3}) compiles but I'm not sure if that works.

Comment: update: found a way to test if tensorflow::TensorShape({3})  works and it does

Comment: Should be #include "tensorflow/cc/framework/ops.h" and then tensorflow::Input::Initializer a({{1, 2}, {3, 4}});

Answer (score 2):

```
tensorflow::Input::Initializer a({{1, 2}, {3, 4}});
```

Actually it works in compiling, but errors when running, which shows that `a` is a tensor with [0] tensorshape.
I don't know where is wrong, but my successful way is:

```
tensorflow::Input::Initializer a({1, 2, 3, 4}, tensorflow::TensorShape({2, 2}));
```