# How to print or cout a tensor?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a tensor that I would like to print for debugging

```
tensorflow::Tensor image_tensor;
```

I tried

```
std::cout << &image_tensor;
```

But I get something like this:

```
0x16fd81cf8I
```

Comment: I have never used tensorflow but it seems like the class has a function for this:
string tensorflow::Tensor::DebugString() const
-----  Use it like:  image_tensor.DebugString()

Comment: Have you tried `std::cout << image_tensor`?

Comment: @KerrekSB yes but it raises a warning, Im using it on Xcode

Comment: I'm voting to close because the exact error message isn't given, and its difficult to evaluate the severity of a "warning" (perhaps mixing up terminology with an "exception").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use the .vec or .flat methods.
let’s say the tensor is a `int8`

```
// for i in image_tensor.size …
cout << i << “ “ << image_tensor.vec<int8>()(i)
```

see also this answer [How to fill a tensor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148671/how-to-fill-a-tensor-in-c)

Answer (score -2):

With `std::cout << &image_tensor;`, you ask to print the address of the tensor - and that's what you got.

Try `std::cout << image_tensor;` (*without* &)