# How to fill the tensor in tensorflow c++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am loading the .pb file in tensorflow c++. Now I need to fill the input tensor with my data and get the output tensors.

To fill data, I am using below code:

```
tensorflow::Tensor points_tensor{tensorflow::DataType::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({number_of_points,4})};
    auto pointsMapped = points_tensor.tensor<float, 2>();
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_points; i++){
        //to the shifting here only
    pointsMapped(i,0) = point_cloud.points[i].x;
    pointsMapped(i,1) = point_cloud.points[i].y;
    pointsMapped(i,2) = point_cloud.points[i].z;
    pointsMapped(i,3) = point_cloud.points[i].intensity;
    }
```

point_cloud is a vector of point object.

But I do not think so, it is better way to do it in c++. Because I need to access my tensor shape so.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: will this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148671/how-to-fill-a-tensor-in-c

Comment: @CppProgrammer23 I checked it already, But I could not able to figure out how to fill the tensor with that answer. can you help me with that?

Comment: what you don't understand? can you pinpoint a specific point so I can explain?

Comment: @CppProgrammer23  in the link, they are filling a 1d tensor, like a.vec<float>()(0). But I need to fill n-d tensor for an example (200,4). I can not use above line of code to do it . I just need to know what is the signature to fill tensor in tensorflow

Comment: I found this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/fill can this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Actually The above mentioned method is the better way to fill the tensor in tensorflow